# Parse specific output from json with jq

Tags: json, parsing, jq

I am new for jq and been trying to get desired output, but without success.

So let's say I have json content like this:

```
{  
    "name": "jack",  
    "tags": ["1.0", "2.0"]  
}
```

And I would like to get ouput like this:

```
jack:1.0  
jack:2.0
```

How to achieve that with jq?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
jq -r '"\(.name):\(.tags[])"' file.json
```

Comment: hey can you please explain what is going on in the background to print this? looks pretty cool!